# Getting the Second Word in a Python 3 String

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a terminal in python, in which I can enter commands and have the program execute certain actions. I want to assign a variable to the string I get from an input like so :

`cmd = input("Enter your command:")`

Lets say I'm trying to make a Logging Command, where I would type out `log primary {text}' (which would store a string in a primary dictionary) or` log secondary {text} (which would store the string in a secondary dictionary).

I want to be able to assign a variable to the second word in the command string. When I type `log primary`, I want to assign a variable to the word `primary` only.

In another words, how do I assign a variable to the second and third words of a string? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: `cmd.split(' ')` will create a list of words. You can extract single words from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var = cmd.split(" ")[1]
```

Here we are just splitting the string into an list and the criteria is " " (space)
then its just indexing through the list.

Thats it !

Comment: Indexing in Python starts at zero. If there are leading whitespaces, the indexing has to change (let's assume there aren't any, but to be safer a regex could be used, or `strip` the string first).

Answer (score 2):

You can enter:

```
cmd = input('Enter command:')
dictionary = cmd.split(' ')[1]
text = cmd.split(' ')[2:]
```

The `dictionary` variable will have the dictionary name, and `text` will have the text you want passed into the dictionary.

PS: the split command splits a string at certain characters. For example:

```
text = 'Hello world!'
text = text.split('o')
print(text)
```

will print:

```
['hell', ' w', 'rld!']
```